# Re-writing json api curl from javascript to php

Tags: javascript, php, json, curl

Hello great stackoverflow, am trying to re-write the api below from javascript to php in other to be able to make json curl but displays error below

```
Warning: curl_setopt() expects exactly 3 parameters, 4 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\firstcare\curl.php on line 15
```

js curl

```
curl -X POST
 "http://my_api.com/accesstoken?grant_type=client_credentials" 
  -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 
  -d 'client_id=$myClient_id' 
  -d 'client_secret=$myClient_secret
```

php curl conversion

```
<?php
// 0 means unlimited timeout
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);

$data = array(
        'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'client_id' => 'myclient_id',
        'client_secret'  => 'myclient_secret'           
);
$url='http://my_api.com/accesstoken?grant_type=client_credentials';
$ch = curl_init();
// Disable SSL verification
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url,$data);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$json = json_decode($result, true);


echo '<pre>' . print_r($json, true) . '</pre>';

?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Error was thrown because `curl_setopt` requires 3 parameters - you've passed 4 here:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url,$data);
```

Comment: how do i make it 3 parameters and ensures that the code works

Answer (score 0):

May I suggeest guzzlehttp, wrapper for curll...also u seem to be passing headers in $data as the forth paramenter remove $data. If u want to sent cllient id as GET  append the $url with http_build_query()

Comment: So in what way is it not working, what error. Does the credentialls require post or get to be sent

Answer (score 0):

Try these codes

```
<?php
// 0 means unlimited timeout
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);

$postdata = array(
        'client_id' => 'myclient_id',
        'client_secret'  => 'myclient_secret'           
);

$header = array(
       'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
);

$url='http://my_api.com/accesstoken?grant_type=client_credentials';
$ch = curl_init();
// Disable SSL verification
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, true); //if you want headers
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);    

$result=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$json = json_decode($result, true);


echo '<pre>' . print_r($json, true) . '</pre>';

?>
```